# I am able to compile the java program but not able to run a java program

Tags: java, linux

When I run the java program it gives following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: check
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: check
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: check. Program will exit.
```

The source code is:

```
import java.io.*;
class check {

    public static void main (String [] args)
            {
            System.out.println("Hello");
            }
    }
```

~
~

Comment: When you run what Java program?

Comment: You run what Java program when?

Comment: What did your program source code look like? Did you include a `public static void main(String args[]) { ... }` function definition in the class that you're trying to execute? How exactly did you compile and then try to run your program?

Comment: Show your source code. This means something is wrong with your program.

Comment: import java.io.*;

class check {

        public static void main (String [] args)
                {
                System.out.println("Hello");
                }
        }
~                                                                               
~

Comment: The file called check.java and I am running from command prompt.

Comment: $javac check.java and then $java check

Comment: check this http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6290

Comment: @DaveNewton not true. The main class doesn't have to be public (though it's a good habit to get into).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the `CLASSPATH` environment variable set, and it doesn't include `.` (dot), the current directory. Try this

```
java -cp . check
```

(That's java space dash cp space dot space check).

Comment: How can I fix it, classpath is not in .bashrc. In .bashrc I have export PATH=$PATH:~/j2sdk1.6.0.18/bin

Comment: It might be set in `.profile`, or `/etc/profile`, or `/etc/bashrc`, or possibly other places depending on how your system is set up.

Comment: You don't fix it. You use -cp appropriately each time.

Comment: IMO he *should* fix it -- he should remove it altogether. Setting `CLASSPATH` in the environment is virtually always a bad idea. The default, in that case, will just be `.`; to look anywhere else, `-cp` will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by set the class path first then compile and execute the class Then your problem will be resolved.

For example at command prompt:

```
C:\> setclasspath=%classpath%;.;
C:\> javac check.java
C:\> java check
```

Now, you will get the output as `Hello`.